# IOS 16 UITableViewCell accessibility API not working, breaking XCTest

Tags: ios, swift, xctest, uiaccessibility, ios16

Since the upgrade to IOS 16 the accessibility api for cells has stopped working.
Using this API's is not working anymore:

In a `CellConfiguration`

```
public struct CellConfiguration: UIContentConfiguration {

    public func makeContentView() -> UIView & UIContentView {
        CellContent(configuration: self)
    }

    public func updated(for state: UIConfigurationState) -> CellConfiguration {
        self
    }
}

private class CellContent: UIView, UIContentView {

  init(configuration: UIContentConfiguration) {
      self.configuration = configuration
      super.init(frame: .zero)
      isAccessibilityElement = true
      accessibilityLabel = "I'm a label"
      accessibilityValue = "I'm a value" 
      accessibilityTraits = [.header] // or other traits as well
      accessibilityIdentifier = "cellID" 
   }
}
```

In a `UITableViewController`

```
private func createCell(in tableView: UITableView) -> UITableViewCell? {
    guard let cell = tableView.dequeueReusableCell(withIdentifier: "cellIdentifier")
    else { return nil }

    cell.contentConfiguration = CellConfiguration()
    cell.selectionStyle = .none
    return cell
}
```

The cell is not accessible in the simulator and on the phone. I can't find it. This has worked prior to IOS16. Thus breaking any existing XCTest's and any progress implementing app that has accessibility.

[image: Accessibility inspector]

Answer (score 0):

This is the right way, declare objects and set attributed an constraints:

```
class YourViewController: UIViewController, UITableViewDelegate, UITableViewDataSource {

let cellId = "cellId"
let tableView = UITableView()

override func viewDidLoad() {
    super.viewDidLoad()
    setupTableView()
}

fileprivate func setupTableView() {
    view.backgroundColor = .white
    
    view.addSubview(tableView)
    tableView.topAnchor.constraint(equalTo: view.safeAreaLayoutGuide.topAnchor).isActive = true
    tableView.leadingAnchor.constraint(equalTo: view.leadingAnchor).isActive = true
    tableView.trailingAnchor.constraint(equalTo: view.trailingAnchor).isActive = true
    tableView.bottomAnchor.constraint(equalTo: view.bottomAnchor).isActive = true
    
    tableView.delegate = self
    tableView.dataSource = self
    tableView.translatesAutoresizingMaskIntoConstraints = false
    tableView.register(MyCell.self, forCellReuseIdentifier: cellId) // register your cell
    tableView.backgroundColor = #colorLiteral(red: 0.94826442, green: 0.9495814443, blue: 0.96922189, alpha: 1)
    tableView.separatorColor = UIColor(white: 1, alpha: 0.4)
    //tableView.tableFooterView = UIView()
    if #available(iOS 15.0, *) {
        tableView.sectionHeaderTopPadding = 0 // remove blank space on top o tableView
    } else {
        UITableView.appearance().sectionHeaderTopPadding = CGFloat(0) // remove blank space on top o tableView in old OS
    }
```

now set delegate and datasource:

```
func tableView(_ tableView: UITableView, viewForHeaderInSection section: Int) -> UIView? {
    
    let v = UIView()
    let label = UILabel()
    
    switch section {
    case 0:
        v.backgroundColor = #colorLiteral(red: 0.94826442, green: 0.9495814443, blue: 0.96922189, alpha: 1)
        label.text = "Section 1"
    default:
        label.text = "Section 2"
        v.backgroundColor = #colorLiteral(red: 0.94826442, green: 0.9495814443, blue: 0.96922189, alpha: 1)
    }
    label.translatesAutoresizingMaskIntoConstraints = false
    label.textColor = .systemBlue
    
    v.addSubview(label)
    label.topAnchor.constraint(equalTo: v.topAnchor).isActive = true
    label.leadingAnchor.constraint(equalTo: v.leadingAnchor, constant: 20).isActive = true
    label.trailingAnchor.constraint(equalTo: v.trailingAnchor).isActive = true
    label.bottomAnchor.constraint(equalTo: v.bottomAnchor).isActive = true
    
    return v
}

func tableView(_ tableView: UITableView, heightForHeaderInSection section: Int) -> CGFloat {
    return 30
}

func tableView(_ tableView: UITableView, heightForRowAt indexPath: IndexPath) -> CGFloat {
    return UITableView.automaticDimension
}

func numberOfSections(in tableView: UITableView) -> Int {
    return 2
}

func tableView(_ tableView: UITableView, numberOfRowsInSection section: Int) -> Int {
    switch section {
    case 1:
        return 1
    default:
        return 1
    }
}

func tableView(_ tableView: UITableView, cellForRowAt indexPath: IndexPath) -> UITableViewCell {
    
    let cell = tableView.dequeueReusableCell(withIdentifier: cellId, for: indexPath) as! MyCell
    let section = indexPath.section

    switch section {
    case 0:
        cell.myLabel.text = "Title: I'm a label"
        cell.subtitle.text = "Subtitle: I'm a value"
    default:
        cell.myLabel.text = "Title: I'm a label2"
        cell.subtitle.text = "Subtitle: I'm a value2"
    }
    
    return cell
}
```

Your cell looks like:

```
class MyCell: UITableViewCell {

let myLabel: UILabel = {
    let label = UILabel()
    label.textColor = .black
    label.translatesAutoresizingMaskIntoConstraints = false
    return label
}()

let subtitle: UILabel = {
    let label = UILabel()
    label.textColor = .gray
    label.translatesAutoresizingMaskIntoConstraints = false
    return label
}()

override init(style: UITableViewCell.CellStyle, reuseIdentifier: String?) {
    super.init(style: style, reuseIdentifier: reuseIdentifier)
    contentView.backgroundColor = .white
    
    let stackView = UIStackView(arrangedSubviews: [myLabel, subtitle])
    stackView.distribution = .fillEqually
    stackView.axis = .vertical
    stackView.spacing = 2
    stackView.translatesAutoresizingMaskIntoConstraints = false
    
    contentView.addSubview(stackView)
    stackView.topAnchor.constraint(equalTo: contentView.topAnchor, constant: 20).isActive = true
    stackView.leadingAnchor.constraint(equalTo: contentView.leadingAnchor, constant: 20).isActive = true
    stackView.trailingAnchor.constraint(equalTo: contentView.trailingAnchor).isActive = true
    stackView.bottomAnchor.constraint(equalTo: contentView.bottomAnchor, constant: -20).isActive = true
    
}

required init?(coder: NSCoder) {
    fatalError("init(coder:) has not been implemented")
 }
}
```

this is the result:

[image]

Comment: No, thats not THE correct way to do it. Check out Apples presentation from 2020 regarding modern cell configuration. Apple is pushing for a new architecture model. https://developer.apple.com/videos/play/wwdc2020/10027/

Comment: I know the new way, but old configuration is always the best way (for me) for now. It allows me to easily reach all objects and modify their attributes...

Comment: That is really good though with the old way of working